# Change Object Structure and Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am facing a particular problem that I need to change the structure of a object like:

```
customerPayload = {
      name: 'Name must remain',
      billing_address_street: 'Electric Avenue',
      billing_address_number: 222,
      shipping_address_street: 'Avenue 1',
      shipping_address_number: 1337
    };
```

into this:

```
customerPayload = {
        name: 'Name must remain',
        billing_address: {
            street: 'Electric Avenue',
            number: 222
        },
        shipping_address: {
            street: 'Avenue 1',
            number: 1337
        }
    };
```

I tried something like this:

```
for (var p in customerPayload) {
        if (customerPayload.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (p.includes('billing')) {      
                var b = p.substr(0, 15) + '.' + p.substr(15 + 1);           
                var bAddress = b.split('.')[0];
                var childProp = b.split('.')[1];
                newCustomerPayload[bAddress] = {
                  [childProp]: customerPayload[p]
                };
            }
            // else if shipping ... same thing
        }
    }
```

But the result is an object with only the last changed properties:

```
 customerPayload = {
    billing_address: {
        number: 222
    },
    shipping_address: {
        street: 'Avenue 1'
    }
 };
```

Please, any help?

Comment: Why not doing it manually it will take 4 lines of code I think!

Comment: The object `customerPayload` is a requested body in my server and I cant change the properties names =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to return new object.

```js
var data = {
  name: 'Name must remain',
  billing_address_street: 'Electric Avenue',
  billing_address_number: 222,
  shipping_address_street: 'Avenue 1',
  shipping_address_number: 1337
};

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!e.match('_')) r[e] = data[e]
  else {
    var key = e.split(/_([^_]*)$/)
    if (!r[key[0]]) r[key[0]] = {}
    r[key[0]][key[1]] = data[e]
  }
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What are the rules to split the string? I am not familiar with regex. This is also breaking a property named `invoice_template` and this should remain as it is on new object.

Comment: It breaks string at last `_`.

Comment: You need to define logic how are you splitting string but lets say you only want to split string if it has more then 1 `_` you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1591/